# How Can I Prevent Boat/MAcro(autoclick) apps

Tags: android, macros, autotouch

All

I am making one app for a client, that having some forms and some more functions for their customer, And Customer can fill up and get reward from that process.

But Somehow Boats/Macro [(auto click apps)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prohiro.macro) are disturbing that some user use that's kind of application to repeat those steps.

So I want to know is that

-> **How to know button click by the user or by boats/macro apps Progrmaticallay**?

### EDIT WITH EXAMPLE

suppose Activity has 10 buttons,

We have 30 min  so those users tap the highest buttons he/she got reward with him performance

- this activity repeat after 1task is completed
- someone make AutoClicks for 1 time  and start Macros app
- so this will generate issue with fake data.

Comment: Since it appears that app requires a rooted 'phone to work, could you detect if the 'phone's been rooted and refuse to run on such devices?

Comment: yes that's checked already by today but may b  Macros Have no need for root

Comment: Can i know that  Without root  Macros cant Use ??

Comment: Being able to "click" other apps _feels_ like the sort of thing you'd need root-access for (but I don't _know_ that for certain). If the page for Macros doesn't say whether it needs to be rooted or not, then I guess the only way to be sure is install it on a non-rooted 'phone and see if it works.